# Practical-Islam tag: redundant or not

Tags: discussion

Recently, we had someone tagging a question with `practical-islam`, which seems to be a pretty common tag. Some of us (like myself) don't believe that this tag has much value, so let's discuss it.

Should we keep this tag, or not?

Answer (score 3):

I think we should remove this tag. It doesn't make any more sense than a tag like `islam`.

Islam started out as a practical religion; from the beginning, everything from matters of aqeedah (which get you persecuted) to fiqh (how and when and where to pray) had practical implications.

We see strong statements from scholars about this. For example, 'Umar ibn Al-Khattab (may Allah be pleased with him) was asked "what do I do if such-and-such happens?" He replied "did it happen yet? No? Then come back when it does and we'll figure it out then." (Grossly paraphrased)

The Qur'an itself speaks on this matter, when it says that Adam (alayhi salaam) ate from the fruit tree. **Allah omitted mentioning the specific fruit,** because it doesn't matter; what matters are the lessons (tawbah), the bigger picture (Adam's first skirmish with Shaytan). We don't know what the fruit was, because we don't *need* to know.

Up until today, scholars generally follow these guidelines, and address practical, day-to-day issues; there's little, if anything, that falls into a purely theoretical or hypothetical umbrella, which would be useful.

From this light, the tag makes little sense.